# how to correct incoming data that contains char not in Ascii to unicode before saving to the database

Tags: vb.net

I have a webservice api in vb.net that accepts string. but i cannot control the data coming to this API. I sometimes receive chars in between words in this format (â€“, Á, â€¢ï€,ââ€ï€, etc. ) Is there a way for me to handle these or convert these characters to their correct symbols before saving to the database?

i know that the best solution would be to go after the source where the characters get malformed.. but i'll make that as plan B

my code is already using utf-8 as encoding pattern,  but what if the client that uses my API messed up and inadvertently sent the malformed char thru the API. can i clean that string and convert the malformed char to the correct symbol?

Comment: Handle them how?  What would the "correct symbols" be?  They are valid characters in some character sets.  Is there only a limited set of characters that you consider valid?

Comment: basically here is the replacements i've done.. but these are just some. i know there are many chars specially on the french language that cannot be handled by ascii.. is there a way to correct them on the fly? replacements << ['â€¦', '…']
replacements << ['â€“', '–']
replacements << ['â€™', '’']
replacements << ['â€œ', '“']
replacements << [/â€[[:cntrl:]]/, '”']

Comment: You should be able to influence and determine what the character encoding you are being sent is. Something is not right with either your webservice or the client. Please explain more. Perhaps a Fiddler capture would help.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to accept ASCII characters, you could remove non-ASCII characters by encoding and decoding the string - the default ASCII encoding uses "?" as a substitute for unrecognized characters, so you probably want to override that:

```vb
' Using System.Text

Dim input As String = "âh€eÁlâl€o¢wïo€râlâd€ï€"
Dim ascii As Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(
    "us-ascii",
    New EncoderReplacementFallback(" "),
    New DecoderReplacementFallback(" ")
)
Dim bytes() As Byte = ascii.GetBytes(input)
Dim output As String = ascii.GetString(bytes)
```

Output:

```
 h e l l o w o r l d
```

The replacement given to the En/DecoderReplacementFallback can be empty if you just want to drop the non-ASCII characters.

You could use a different encoding than ASCII if you want to accept more characters - but I would imagine that most of the characters you listed are valid in most European character sets.

Comment: i tried it mark but instead of ascii , I used utf-8. seems it just accepts the characters as valid characters? thus, the string will still be "âh€eÁlâl€o¢wïo€râlâd€ï€" (since its those chars are part of the utf8) .. is there a way to convert those characters into their correct transalation ( ie. â€¢ should be a - , Ãª should be a ê , Ã¨ should be è

Comment: @tesla_coil No, using encoding like this will only filter out characters that are not valid for that particular encoding - and as you saw, all of them are valid in UTF-8.  I don't think this method is useful if you want to perform completely arbitrary conversion of characters (at least I can't see the pattern in the translations you want to do - i.e. how do you know that "â€¢ should be a -"?).

Comment: @tesla_coil From your comments on the other answer, it sounds like the client is using an incorrect encoding - so the right answer would be to tell them to stop! ;-)  You may have to set up a `Dictionary(Of String, String)` with the translations you want to perform and loop through that and use `String.Replace` to do the substitutions.

Comment: thanks mark, i actually gave up converting those malformed chars and ask our client to check their end if they are sending those chars in UTF8 format. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

While you are kind of vague I could guide you in something I think you could potentially do:

```
Sub Main()
   Dim allowedValues = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".ToCharArray()
   Dim someGoodSomeBad = "#@#$#@okay@#$#@"

   Dim onlyGood = New String(someGoodSomeBad.ToCharArray().Where(Function(x) allowedValues.Contains(x)).ToArray)

   Console.WriteLine(onlyGood)
End Sub
```

The first line would be valid characters, in my example I chose to use alpha characters, you could add more characters and numbers too.  Basically you are creating a whitelist of acceptable characters, that you the developer would make.

The next line would be an output from your API that has some good and some bad lines.

The next part is really more simple than it looks.  I am extending the string to be an array of characters, then I am finding ONLY the characters that match my whitelist in a lambda statement.  Then I extend this to an array again because if I do a new String in .NET from a char array.

I then get a good string, but I could make 'good' to be subjective based on a whitelist.

The bigger question though is WHY is your Web API sending garbled data over?  It should be sending well formed JSON or XML that is then able to well parsed and strongly type to models.  Doing what I have shown above is more of a bandaide than a real fix to the underlying problem and it will have MANY holes.

Comment: yup i was thinking something like that but it should also handle french characters? what i did was too do some replacement on the string. but its to tedious (i have to basically put the entire unicode charset on the replace command in order for me to cover all characters)..  here are some of the replacement I did..replacements << ['â€¦', '…']
replacements << ['â€“', '–']
replacements << ['â€™', '’']
replacements << ['â€œ', '“']
replacements << [/â€[[:cntrl:]]/, '”']

Comment: Just add the characters you want.  I could make this section: allowvalues be: "0123456jesuisammi" or add characters by their ASCI designation as well.  It is up to you to maintain the whitelist, it could be anything.

Comment: the data actually comes from the client as is.. meaning we are already receiving the data  as â€™ ,â€œ etc... so i need to cleanse these string first before saving it..  and by cleansing it meaning correcting the characters to their correct values and not removing them all (example.. the character â€œ is supposed to be a curly double quote “.. because we need to preserve the text being sent over to us

Comment: I am completely confused by you, you say this: 'but i cannot control the data coming to this API' then ' but what if the client that uses my API messed up and inadvertently sent the malformed char thru the API'.  Are there two API's?  Generally people don't send others things like "!#$@" as a business model.  They are usually well formed and the encoding that is receiving them needs to be in UTF-16 or another standard or else there is something drastically wrong.  If not there is something wrong further down the line.  You keep saying correct but that is relative to some type of reference.

Comment: sorry about the confusion.. nope its just 1 API.. we are using UTF8 on our application. so if i test my API using postman, even if i induce a dash or elipsis on the words.. it passes thru just fine, because its interpreting the chars correctly due to our use of UTF8..  what i'm basically trying to do is make our API flexible where in just in case the client that uses our API is using the wrong encoding.. our API will still be able to handle it and convert those malformed chars into their correct symbols

Comment: If it is your API where are the junk characters coming from?